# convert a string to javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string

```
":All;true:Yes;false:&nbsp"
```

I want to convert is to an object like:

```
var listItems = 
[
{itemValue: "", itemText: "All"},
{itemValue: true, itemText: "Yes"},
{itemValue: false, itemText: "&nbsp"}
];
```

Any elegant way to doing this appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `true/false` boolean support:

```
var listItems = [];
var yourString = ":All;true:Yes;false:&nbsp";

var arr = yourString.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var arr2 = arr[i].split(":");
    var value = arr2[0] || "";
    if (value == "true" || value == "false")
        value = (value === "true");
    listItems.push({
        itemValue : value,
        itemText : arr2[1] || ""
    });
}

console.log(listItems);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MZKFU/1/

---

**UPDATE.** For universal value parsing you can use `JSON.parse` method with `try/catch` block, as presented in [Esailija's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734055/1249581).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MZKFU/2/

Comment: You might want to make that `var arr2 = arr[i].split(":",1)` which will allow the values to include colons.

Comment: Great, but we'd also have to handle "true" and "false": We don't want them to turn up as strings in the resulting JSON, but as booleans.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It will work only if we have value on the right side :)

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug Yep, I also have thought about that. Now it supports boolean.

Answer (score 6):

```
var str = ":All;true:Yes;false:&nbsp";
var listItems = str.split(/[;:]/g).map( function(v, i, arr){
    var itemValue;
    if( i % 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        itemValue = JSON.parse(v);
    }
    catch(e) {
        itemValue = v;
    }

    return {
        itemValue: itemValue,
        itemText: arr[i + 1]
    };
}).filter( Boolean );
```

Result:

```
[
Object
itemText: "All"
itemValue: ""
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
itemText: "Yes"
itemValue: true
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
itemText: "&nbsp"
itemValue: false
__proto__: Object
]
```

Comment: Best solution. its a shame 'map' isn't used more in javascript.  Its been support in all the major browsers for a while now

Comment: Really clever solution! However it fails if you have any string or number as a value. But it can be easily handled.

Comment: @VisioN should handle it now. Though not strings (other than empty)

Comment: I also tried to use `JSON.parse` here but it raises exception on any random symbol in the string.

Comment: @Vision yes, currently the string needs to be a legit javascript literal (regexp, number, object, array, boolean, null, empty string, etc) or it fails

Comment: Yeah.. The only option I see is to add `try/catch` block.

Comment: @VisioN yep I added that, should be pretty robust now (At the cost of elegance :P)

Comment: @VisioN heh, great to see finns dominating it here :P

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = ":All;true:Yes;false:&nbsp";
var array = string.split(/:|;/);

var listItems = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2 ) {
    listItems.push({itemValue: array[i], itemText: array[i + 1]})
}
```

Notice that this will set "false" and "true" as string. Same for numbers if you have it. If you want save them with the proper types, you have to add a manual conversion. Something like:

```
function value(val) {
    if (!isNaN(val))
        return +val;

    if (val === "true")
        return true;

    if (val === "false")
        return false;

    return val;
}
```

Therefore the line that push the object to the array will change as below:

```
    listItems.push({itemValue: value(array[i]), itemText: array[i + 1]})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = ":All;true:Yes;false:&nbsp"; 
var myArray = myString.split(';');
var literal = [];
for(var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
  var mixed_string = myArray[i];
  var changed_array = mixed_string.split(":");
  var key = changed_array[0];
  var value = changed_array[1];
  literal.push({key:value});
}
console.log(literal);
```

​