# convert string to javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
"{INDIA=99, PAKISTAN=30}"
```

i am having string in this form , want to convert into json object. 
Have tried

`JSON.parse({INDIA=99, PAKISTAN=30}).`

but getting errors

> VM2602:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 1

Comment: What about this: JSON.parse('{"INDIA":99, "PAKISTAN":30}')

Comment: That string is not JSON so can't be parsed as such. Parse it manually or replace() whats needed to make it look like JSON (ymmv doing that).

Comment: If your string really _does_ look like that, can you go back to wherever it's coming from and alter the output?  If you can make it standard JSON, your job will be much easier.

Comment: Would following work for you ?JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse("{INDIA=99, PAKISTAN=30}" );

Comment: @Amit this is not a valid JSON

Comment: @Amit Nor is this Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a string to javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733898/convert-a-string-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your string:

1. Keys and values are separated by colon(`:`) and not by equals to(`=`).
2. Keys should be wrapped in quotes.

Though the best way would be to rectify the JSON(input string) string itself, you can try this approach to create an object from current string.

> **Note:** This is not a robust solution. Since this solution is relying on commas in string to split, if this pattern is available in a value like `{India=100, 000, 000}`, this solution will fail. So treat this as your last resort. String manipulation will never be 100% covered.

```js
var str = "{INDIA=99, PAKISTAN=30}";
var kv = str.substring(1, str.length -1);

var list = kv.split(", ");
var result = list.reduce(function(p,c){
  var parts = c.split('=');
  p[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  return p;
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great solution. Might suit his needs if he cannot alter the original content.

Answer (score 2):

Your input isn't valid JSON. You can try to transform it into an appropriate string and then call `JSON.parse` as you tried. See snippet below and feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

```js
const str = "{INDIA=99, PAKISTAN=30}";
const result = JSON.parse(str.replace(/\=/g, ':').replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, '"$1"'));

console.log(result);
console.log(result['INDIA']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `replace` and `split` the string .And create the object with `Array#forEach`

```js
var str ="{INDIA=99, PAKISTAN=30}" ;
var c = str.replace(/[\}\{]/g,'').trim().split(',')
var res={};
c.forEach(a=> res[a.split('=')[0].trim()] = a.split('=')[1].trim())
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying valid JSON.

In order for `JSON.parse()` to work, you need to supply a valid JSON.

Example:

`{"INDIA": 99, "PAKISTAN": 30}`

in your code:

```
JSON.parse('{"INDIA": 99, "PAKISTAN": 30}');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have characters around the key, otherwise it won't read.
So:

```
var str = '{"INDIA":99, "PAKISTAN":30}'
JSON.parse(str);
```

That should work.

Comment: there is = not : in between

Comment: I do believe it is supposed to be ':'

Answer (score 0):

This

```
JSON.parse('{"INDIA":99, "AKISTAN":30}')
```